# Firebase authentication not working on a phone, but works fine on a computer browser

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps

I've made a progressive web app with React, using Firebase authentication:
https://mfahelper.netlify.app/

Logging in works fine on my computer. And I believe it worked well with my phone (android using Chrome) a few months ago when I tried it. The problem is that now it appears to log in and then takes me back to being logged out (and redirects to the log in page).

There's no error messages or anything to give me a clue. Nothing in the firebase console either. Just looking for the best way to figure it out.

Comment: How did you fix it? I see it works for mobile on the site you mentioned in question. I am having same issue right now. Searching whole web..

I tried both methods.. still doesnt work in mobile browsers.
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)

Comment: I believe it was a cookie issue. I think Chrome on mobile, and Safari block 3rd party cookies. How are you getting on?

Comment: Hey, it worked for me.. I just had an overlapping container with opacity 0 on top of login/sign up buttons. It was overlapping when device was smaller & with larger width viewport it use to go on sides.. It was so silly of me, I surfed github issues, so many stack overflow questions, official docs & many people 

Comment: By the way, I have allowed Pop ups on both iPhone & Android devices from privacy settings & it worked with firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) but then i switched back to redirect, just dont want users to touch additional settings for using web app.

Comment: Oh, well I'm glad you got it working. Those little issues can often be the biggest headache to work out! Good luck with your app :-)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but i'm struggling with the same issue. i have no idea why the auth doesn't work out of a sudden on mobile device.... do you happen to remember how to fix that issue? it will be a huge help.